# What is the use of generated CHECK CONSTRAINT sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, check-constraints

In `SSMS`, if I open a table with constraints, right click on one and select "Script Constraint As" > "CREATE TO", these are the lines that are generated automatically:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table] DROP CONSTRAINT [CK_table_col]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [CK_table_col] CHECK (([col] IN('SUP', 'ADM')))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_table_col]
GO
```

I get what the first two lines do, that's not a problem. However, the `CHECK CONSTRAINT` at the end seems unclear. If I remove it, it still checks that the existing records match the new constraint. If I run the `CHECK CONSTRAINT` on it's own, it just tells me that the query succeeded... Why is it needed? What does it do?

Comment: What is your SSMS version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `CONSTRAINT` can be disabled, using `NOCHECK`. This cannot be done when you `CREATE` the `CONSTRAINT`, but has to be done explicitly afterwards, such as with the following:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable NOCHECK CONSTRAINT chk_MyTable;
```

If you disable a constraint and then use the `CREATE TO` script option, then that would be reflected too. As such SSMS explicitly defines whether the constraint is to be checked or not afterwards. Although yes enforcing the `CHECK` is redundant, it creates consistent scripts.